# ODBC Connection to Informix Database

Tags: odbc, informix

I am looking to connect Cisco UCCX database using ODBC Data Source Adminsitrator (32-bit). But when I connect I get below error.

I was able to connect successfully previously but recently have been getting this error.

See the screenshot of error:

[image]

**IBM INFORMIX ODBC Setup**

[image]

Comment: What is the sqlhosts file parameter set to?  How is it set?  What is in the file?  What changed recently?

Comment: I have not set anything. I have attached the ODBC Driver setup screenshot above.

Comment: The 'options' value showed in the screenshot is not recognized by the driver. Looks like a password to me. Leave it blank and check if the application can connect or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try 123456 for uccxhruser.
And try to change host name to 'itsuccxpub01'
And leave option blank